# how to add multiple elements from json file to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a object and I attempting to add both the name and description to the html body:

```
$('div#mydiv').html((j.root[D - 1].Name), (j.root[D - 1].Description));
```

However only the name is showing when I run it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.html` does not take multiple arguments. Use `+` for concatenation to combine all the strings into a single argument.

```
$('div#mydiv').html(j.root[D-1].Name + ' ' + j.root[D-1].Description);
```